# WPF window freezes when dragged between monitors

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a proof of concept application to evaluate the performance we may (or may not) expect if we move our main product to using vector icons instead of bitmaps. So far the results are very encouraging, except for one major issue. When moving the window from one monitor to the other, there's a long freeze as the window touches the end of the one screen, before starting to show on the next. Basically, as long as the window spans both monitors in any way, it moves in a very slow and stuttering way. The weird thing is that as long as it is only on monitor all is well. Dragging of the screen, resizing, minimizing and maximizing, dragging to dock at either side, all is speedy and fluid.

The window I'm creating just has a WrapPanel on it. In the OnLoaded handler, I add elements to the panel in the following way

```
Brush brush = Application.Current.FindResource("ICO_Trashcan") as Brush;
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle()
            {
                Width = 18,
                Height = 18,
                SnapsToDevicePixels = true,
                Fill = brush
            };
            _wrapPanel.Children.Add(rect);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle()
            {
                Width = 32,
                Height = 32,
                SnapsToDevicePixels = true,
                Fill = brush
            };
            _wrapPanel.Children.Add(rect);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle()
            {
                Width = 60,
                Height = 60,
                SnapsToDevicePixels = true,
                Fill = brush
            };
            _wrapPanel.Children.Add(rect);
        }
```

The brush resource is a DrawingBrush i downloaded from Xamalot.com. I picked the trashcan icon because it has reasonable complexity and uses a fair number of gradients. I have RenderingOptions.CachingHint="Cache" set on the DrawingBrush. I tried freezing the brush, but it made no difference.

The window loads very fast, many orders of magnitude faster than the equivalent code using PNGs. I just can't figure out why dragging between monitors is such a bad experience.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT:

The XAML of the window is tiny:

```
<Window x:Class="VectorIconEvaluation.VectorWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded"
    LocationChanged="Window_LocationChanged"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Background="#202020"
    Title="VectorWindow" Height="1000" Width="1500">
<Grid UseLayoutRounding="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
    <WrapPanel x:Name="_wrapPanel"/>
</Grid>
```

This it just a proof of concept, so the use of MVVM is irrelevant. The full application does use MVVM.

Comment: Post the full XAML so we can easily reproduce.

Comment: Same resolution on each monitor, both horizontal orientation? Same behavior on every machine you test on? I'm wondering why you're adding 600 rectangles also. You can't process 600 images at once of those sizes in my experience. Try setting `SnapToDevicePixels = false`. Also test to see I'd same behavior occurs when adding maybe 20, 50, even 100 rectangles. Highmore is suggesting you use MVVM, and I agree; in that case you wouldn't have any code-behind.

Comment: Monitors are identical. Windows 7, so same DPI. Same behavior across dev machines. Doing the same thing with 600 Image objects (or more) filled with bitmaps of the same icon works just fine and does not display the problem dragging across monitors. Vector icons are noticeably sharper and scale better, so I would love to find a solution.

Comment: SnapsToDevicePixels=false makes no difference. Adding only 10 rectangles all is fine, and problem gets progressively worse with the number of icons displayed. At around 50 icons it's noticeable enough to be problematic

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get this out, so eventually had to implement a class that caches the DrawingBrush as an ImageBrush, and updates on SizeChanged. Not an ideal solution, but acceptable.

If anyone can think of something better, I'm all ears...